# Span WPF Datagrid rows/columns

Tags: c#, wpf

There's a couple of similar questions on here regarding this, but they show how to split one column into two by places a 2 column grid in the cell, I want to do the opposite.

```
+------+----------------+------+
| To   | Subject        | Date |
+------+----------------+------+
| john | test 1         |      |
| two column span       |      |
+------+----------------+------+
| tom  | test 2         |      |
| two column span       |      |
+------+----------------+------+
```

If there's an easier way to do it with other controls I'm open to that as well. My only requirement is to allow the user to resize the columns and the rows will be dynamic (databound)

Here's a photoshop of the expected outcome
[image]

Comment: Is `two column span` supposed to be it's own row? If so, what is to be contained in this row?

Comment: If you created a 2 column, 2 row Grid and had the second row span 2 columns you'd get the same thing. The problem is that if you do this with a Grid the resizing of the header grid line between To and Subject doesn't sync with the grid in the cell/row.

Comment: @kill4silence I updated the question with an image better explaining the outcome.

Comment: You can still do it how you suggested I think. There is the capability to share grid widths across grids via [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx). Look into that, that might give you the desired results.

Comment: Kudos for the interesting suggestion, but unfortunately (as quoted): `true if this instance of Grid is sharing size properties with another Grid; otherwise, false.` OP is using a DataGrid.